# How to specify the special time in one column using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with on input and date and time. Here I just want to convert time into 00:00:00 for specific value which is contain in input column, and other time will be display as it is. 
Then I wrote the code for that.
Then what I want is specify that 00:00:00 only. So I wrote the code for it and got an error  `'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'strftime'"

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

My code :

```
df['time_diff']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + " " + df['time'],
                format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
mask = df['x3'].eq(5)
df['Duration'] = np.where(df['x3'].eq(5), np.timedelta64(0), pd.to_timedelta(df['time']))
```

Then I got the output:

```html
        date      time  x3 Duration
0   10/3/2018   6:15:00   0 06:15:00
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5 00:00:00
2   10/3/2018   7:45:00   0 07:45:00
3   10/3/2018   9:00:00   0 09:00:00
4   10/3/2018   9:25:00   0 09:25:00
5   10/3/2018   9:30:00   0 09:30:00
6   10/3/2018  11:00:00   0 11:00:00
7   10/3/2018  11:30:00   0 11:30:00
8   10/3/2018  13:30:00   0 13:30:00
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5 00:00:00
10  10/3/2018  15:00:00   0 15:00:00
11  10/3/2018  15:25:00   0 15:25:00
12  10/3/2018  16:25:00   0 16:25:00
13  10/3/2018  18:00:00   0 18:00:00
14  10/3/2018  19:00:00   0 19:00:00
15  10/3/2018  19:30:00   0 19:30:00
16  10/3/2018  20:00:00   0 20:00:00
17  10/3/2018  22:05:00   0 22:05:00
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5 00:00:00
19  10/3/2018  23:40:00   0 23:40:00
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5 00:00:00
21  10/4/2018  13:00:00   0 13:00:00
22  10/4/2018  16:00:00   0 16:00:00
23  10/4/2018  17:00:00   0 17:00:00
```

Then I want to specify this 00:00:00 time only then :

```
match_time="00:00:00"
time = data['duration'].loc[data.index.strftime("%H:%M:%S") == match_time]
```

Got an error :

[image]

Expected output :

```
time   
00:00:00
00:00:00
Just read only 00:00:00 time
```

My csv :
subset:

```html
date time x3
10/3/2018 6:15:00         0
10/3/2018 6:45:00  5
10/3/2018 7:45:00   0
10/3/2018 9:00:00         0
10/3/2018 9:25:00         0
10/3/2018 9:30:00   0
10/3/2018 11:00:00 0
10/3/2018 11:30:00 0
10/3/2018 13:30:00 0
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 0
10/3/2018 15:25:00 0
10/3/2018 16:25:00 0
10/3/2018 18:00:00 0
10/3/2018 19:00:00 0
10/3/2018 19:30:00 0
10/3/2018 20:00:00 0
10/3/2018 22:05:00 0
10/3/2018 22:15:00 5
10/3/2018 23:40:00 0
10/4/2018 6:58:00         5
10/4/2018 13:00:00 0
10/4/2018 16:00:00 0
10/4/2018 17:00:00 0
```

My csv file :
[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because types of values in column `Duration` are timedeltas, compare by string converted to timedelta too:

```
print (data['Duration'].dtype)
#timedelta64[ns]

match_time="00:00:00"
time = data[data['Duration'] == pd.to_timedelta(match_time)]
print (time)
         date      time  x3 Duration
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5   0 days
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5   0 days
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5   0 days
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5   0 days
```

EDIT: If always timedeltas are less like 1 day:

First convert timedeltas to strings - added 0 days:

```
print (df['Duration'].astype(str))
#0     0 days 06:15:00.000000000
#1     0 days 00:00:00.000000000
#2     0 days 07:45:00.000000000
#3     0 days 09:00:00.000000000
#4     0 days 09:25:00.000000000
#5     0 days 09:30:00.000000000
#6     0 days 11:00:00.000000000
#7     0 days 11:30:00.000000000
#8     0 days 13:30:00.000000000
#9     0 days 00:00:00.000000000
#10    0 days 15:00:00.000000000
#11    0 days 15:25:00.000000000
#12    0 days 16:25:00.000000000
#13    0 days 18:00:00.000000000
#14    0 days 19:00:00.000000000
#15    0 days 19:30:00.000000000
#16    0 days 20:00:00.000000000
#17    0 days 22:05:00.000000000
#18    0 days 00:00:00.000000000
#19    0 days 23:40:00.000000000
#20    0 days 00:00:00.000000000
#21    0 days 13:00:00.000000000
#22    0 days 16:00:00.000000000
#23    0 days 17:00:00.000000000
#Name: Duration, dtype: object
```

And then remove first and last part of strings by slicing:

```
print (df['Duration'].astype(str).str[-18:-10])
#0     06:15:00
#1     00:00:00
#2     07:45:00
#3     09:00:00
#4     09:25:00
#5     09:30:00
#6     11:00:00
#7     11:30:00
#8     13:30:00
#9     00:00:00
#10    15:00:00
#11    15:25:00
#12    16:25:00
#13    18:00:00
#14    19:00:00
#15    19:30:00
#16    20:00:00
#17    22:05:00
#18    00:00:00
#19    23:40:00
#20    00:00:00
#21    13:00:00
#22    16:00:00
#23    17:00:00
#Name: Duration, dtype: object
```

---

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype(str).str[-18:-10]

match_time="00:00:00"
time = df[df['Duration'] == match_time]
print (time)
         date      time  x3  Duration
1   10/3/2018   6:45:00   5  00:00:00
9   10/3/2018  13:50:00   5  00:00:00
18  10/3/2018  22:15:00   5  00:00:00
20  10/4/2018   6:58:00   5  00:00:00
```

Solution for all timedeltas:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)) 

df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].apply(f)

match_time="00:00:00"
time = df[df['Duration'] == match_time]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. But when I applied your code it gave me this error " name 'timedelta64' is not defined"

Comment: @team - it is only test, `timedelta64[ns]` is returned after run `print (data['Duration'].dtype)`

Comment: When I used your code , then it removed the first data and read which is having value 5 rows only. But I need keeping that time as it is and just separate the 00:00:00 only

Comment: date                 time                        x3     Duration
1  2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
9  2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
18 2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
20 2018-10-04  2018-10-04 00:00:00   5  00:00:00     just like this not changing the data csv values. @jezrael

Comment: @team - yes, because for 5 values are `00:00:00` values in `Duration` column.

Comment: @ jezrael Can you help me with this code please ? This code is correct but giving an error"'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime' "

Comment: @team - Give me some time for answer.

Comment: @ jezrael  Yes sure Thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: @ jezrael  code is this:   "match_time="00:00:00"
A  = df['duration'].apply(lambda x: x.strptime("%H:%M:%S"))==match_time"

Comment: Thank you very much. Jezrael I have one question, Can I only take duration column without whole data in df?

Comment: @team - Use `time = df.loc[df['Duration'] == match_time, 'Duration']`

Comment: Omg thank you very much. I was stucked with this code in two days. Can you explain me why did you use this code"df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype(str).str[-18:-10]"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert the dataframe index (0,1,2,...23) to a string time format object, and not the items content in the 'Duration' column.

First convert each item in the column 'Duration' then compare it to 'match_time' and finally save the resulting sliced frame, all at once:

```
match_time="00:00:00"
df=data.loc[data['Duration'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))==match_time]
```

Then you will get all indexes which match your desired 'match_time' as follows:

```
         date                 time  x3  Duration
1  2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
9  2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
18 2018-10-03  2018-10-03 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
20 2018-10-04  2018-10-04 00:00:00   5  00:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. Then I used this code as you provide earlier. Then I got an error "'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
" Can you provide me full code if you are okay?